# Django Template IF inside Listing FOR

Tags: django, for-loop, if-statement, templates

I am tryin use an object from a listing in an IF structure inside the FOR LOOP, but when I am trying to compare the object whit a String (That is 'TRUE'), I can not go inside the True case lines of the IF structure.

Example:
When equipo.Department = "Equipo", i don know why the IF ({% if equipo.Department == 'Equipo' %}) is not working.

Code:

```
{% autoescape off %}

{% if equipos %}
{% for equipo in equipos %}
<tr></tr>
    <td>{% if equipo.Department == 'Equipo' %}
        E
        {% else %}{{ equipo.Department }}{% endif %}-{{ equipo.Equipment_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.Description }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.SerialNo }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.Vendor }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.Tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.OutOfService }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.Location }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.Plan }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.ManualPath }}</td>
    <td>{{ equipo.ImagePath }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h1>No existen registros</h1>
{% endif %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: `Department` is likely not a `CharField`, but a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: Is it possible to be a bit more *responsive*.

Comment: Willem, your are Right Department comes froma ForeingKey:

Comment: Department = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: @RogelioGonzlez: can you please share the relevant models (the model of the items in your `equipos`) and the one the `Department` is referring to (`Departamento`)? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: can you [edit] the question and share the model of the `equipos` and the `Departmento` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Department` object with `'Equipo'` as name is *not* the same as the string '`Equipo'`, so the check itself is false. If you later *render* `{{ equipo.Department }}`, then Django will call the `str(..)` method on that result, and thus it will indeed *render* the name of the department.

You thus should check the equivalence with:

```
{% if equipo.Department.name == 'Equipo' %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endif %}
```

That being said, instead of filtering in the template, you better should filter at the database end, so usually it is better to try to *avoid* retrieving `equipo` that is not of the required department.

You can filter for example with:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(Department__name='Equipo')
```

> **Note**: Django has a [**`{% for … %}…{% empty %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) that
>   can be used to render a message if the collection you iterate over is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used equipo.Departmen.Name and it is working now